# LinkedList of BufferedImage

Tags: java, animation, linked-list, bufferedimage

I am trying to optimize the Animation class I've built using a tutorial but I get a NullPointerException whenever I try to add a BufferedImage to a LinkedList of type BufferedImage.

This is my code:

```
public class Animation
{
    private int speed;
    private int frames;
    private int index = 0;
    private int count = 0;

    private LinkedList<BufferedImage> img;

    private BufferedImage currentImg;


    public Animation(int speed, BufferedImage img1, BufferedImage img2)
    {
        this.speed = speed;

        img.add(img1);
        img.add(img2);
    }
}
```

Why can't I add the BufferedImage to the LinkedList?

Comment: where do you initialize `img`? You should do that before adding elements to this LinkedList... How do you call this constructor?

Comment: I've tried this

anim = new Animation(
                2,
                game.getBufferedImage(0, 0),
                game.getBufferedImage(0, 1))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to create a new LinkedList before adding images to it

Right now you are merely declaring a pointer to it, so img is probably something like null when you try to add to it.

`img = new LinkedList<BufferedImage>();`